# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I think there is a strange problem with jquery I got this exception when page load 
here is my markup :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link href="../Layouts/en-us/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../Layouts/en-us/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/Layouts/en-us/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

here is the function that causes error

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    if ($("#ListBoxPages").val() == null) {
        $("#tabs").css("display", "none");
    }

    $("#ListBoxPages").change(function () {
        $("#tabs").css("display", "block");
    });

});
```

All relative paths to Layouts and jquery were copied from another markup which works pretty fine with no error

Comment: Make sure `jquery-ui.min.js` is loaded

Comment: Your script order can be the source of the problem : 

    `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Layouts/en-us/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Comment: @Ibrahim Amer Check my answer and try that solution..

Comment: so what solution did you opt for? cause I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 6):

I can see that you are loading jquery twice so try to remove that

`<script src="/Layouts/en-us/js/jquery-ui.min.js" />`

and keep only -

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
```

then use below code in place of your function (First check by changes in this function then try with removing that jquery-ui.min.js)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        if ($("#ListBoxPages").val() == null) {
            $("#tabs").css("display", "none");
        }
        $("#ListBoxPages").change(function () {
            $("#tabs").css("display", "block");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

$("#tabs").tabs(); requires Jquery.UI just include

```
<script src="/Layouts/en-us/js/jquery-ui.min.js" />
```

or use CDN

```
<scriptsrc="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```